# addToBackStack not working with onBackPressed method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have created a tabbed activity inside a navigation drawer activity. I have linked the lists inside the navigation drawer with individual fragments. I also used the command ft.addToBackStack(null) before ft.commit(). It was perfectly fine and I was able to use it to close the fragments inside the navigation drawer. now I have created webviews inside the fragments of the tabbed activity (home page). I added the onBackPressed to go back inside the webview and now the addToBackStack method stopped working.

For the navigation drawer fragments,

```
private void dispaySelectedScreen(int id) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.fragment1:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case R.id.fragment2:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case R.id.fragment3:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        case R.id.fragment4:
            fragment = new fragment4();
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

onBackPressed Method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (hWebView.canGoBack()) {
        hWebView.goBack();
    } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())

        if (sWebView.canGoBack()) {
            sWebView.goBack();
        } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())

            if (dWebView.canGoBack()) {
                dWebView.goBack();
            } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate());



}
```

Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code: override `onBackPressed()` in your tabbed activity (home page).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (hWebView.canGoBack()) {
        hWebView.goBack();
    } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

Comment: not working for me.. whenever i am clicking back inside the webview, it is killing the app..

Comment: add the code in activity and use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead

Comment: the fragments alligned with the list inside the navigation drawer are closing when i press the back button showing the main activity however the back button in the  webview (hWebView inside the tabbed fragment) is not workig and pressing back button is kiling the app..

Comment: so back press woking for your  `fragment`? but not in the `Webview Fragment` ?

Comment: Hey it worked.. I only added ..................FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (hWebView.canGoBack()) {
            hWebView.goBack();
        } else if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())


        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}